# Django Rest Framework: how to route a uuid to an associated object?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am building a simple photos-albums app with Django Rest Framework (DRF). Each album has a UUID field in its model. I want to create 'share links' so that someone with a link of the form `/albums/[uuid]` will be able to access that album.

I am using `ModelViewSet` for my views, so I assume that the most succinct way to achieve this desired routing is via the `action` decorator, with urls like `/albums/shared/[uuid]`, but it's not clear to me how to obtain the uuid in the action-decorated `shared` method. I can't even parse the URL because DRF will 404 before firing this `shared` method:

```
### views/album.py

class AlbumViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    
    queryset = Album.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AlbumSerializer

    @action(detail=False, methods=['get'])
    def shared(self, request):

        # How do you get the uuid from the supplied URL?
        uuid = ???
        obj = self.get_queryset().objects.get(uuid=uuid)
        return Response([obj])
```

Hopefully I won't have to add any fancy patterns to `urls.py`, but if I do then here is what I have so far:

```
### myapp/urls.py

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'albums', AlbumViewSet)
...

urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]

format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you need to some changes in `url-pattern` and your `action-decorater`:

**First Change :**

`/albums/shared/[uuid]`  **to** `/albums/[uuid]/shared/`  According to [Docs.](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing)

**Second Change :**

```
class AlbumViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    
    queryset = Album.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AlbumSerializer

                   ⬇⬇⬇⬇
    @action(detail=True, methods=['get'])
    def shared(self,request,pk=None): ⬅⬅⬅⬅
        uuid = pk
        obj = self.get_queryset().objects.get(uuid=uuid)
        return Response([obj])
```

Pass **UUID** in `url` and fetch it in `view`... For ex.  `/albums/45/shared/`

Comment: Perfect - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by @Pradip is perfect but, for my own reference, here is a different solution I got working (except query part not tested!):

```
### myapp/views/album.py

class AlbumViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...

    @action(detail=False, methods=['get'],)
    def shared(self, request,   *args, **kwargs):
        uuid = kwargs.get('uuid', None)
        if uuid:
            try:
                obj = self.get_queryset().get(name=uuid)
                return Response([obj])
            except Album.DoesNotExist:
                obj = None
                raise exceptions.NotFound(f'Album with UUID {uuid} not found')
        else:
            raise exceptions.ParseError('UUID not parseable')


### myproject/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('albums/<str:uuid>/shared/', AlbumViewSet.as_view({'get': 'shared'})),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Actions are great, but if you need to support multiple crud operations or ViewSet features like pagination or filtering, it's easier to map another ViewSet via `router.register(...)`

```
router.register(r'album', AlbumViewSet)
router.register(r'album/(?P<album_uuid>[\w-]+)/photo', PhotoViewSet)

class PhotoViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    # Filter photos by album uid
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        return qs.filter(album_id=self.kwargs["album_uuid"])
```